# download file from ftp not working

Tags: php, ftp

i have following code for download file from ftp client is.

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "IP";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "USER", "PASSWORD");

$local_file = "files/syslog.txt";
$server_file = "syslog/syslog.txt";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
{
   echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
}
else
{
   echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

?>
```

but when i run this program i get following error.

```
Warning: ftp_get(files/syslog.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\demo\schedule_readtxt.php on line 11

Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening files/syslog.txt in C:\wamp\www\demo\schedule_readtxt.php on line 11
Error downloading syslog/syslog.txt.
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that you don't have permission to write to `files/syslog.txt` file on your system

Answer (score 1):

I think you've a permission issue.

It seems to me that you are trying to write a file "syslog.txt" in a folder that's not existing: "files" or your script can't access.

Does the folder "files" exists beside your php script?
And if it does, does apache (or the user that runs the php script) has the right to write and access this folder?

Answer (score -1):

change variable $local_file to full path "C:\path\to\file\syslog.txt" also make Apache have write permission to that folder